# Why must $r$ be put in modulus for $\int^{\infty}_0\frac{1-\cos(rx)}{x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}|r|$?

Tags: calculus

Here's the question: Prove that $$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{1-\cos(rx)}{x^2}~\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi}{2}|r|·$$

When I finished my working, I got $\frac{\pi}{2}r$

Why is the $r$ put in modulus? Is it because the graph lies entirely above the x axis?

Comment: Did you assume $r\geq 0$ in your working?

Comment: The integral expression is visibly even in $r$. As for where the absolute value comes up in your derivation, that depends on your method, I suppose.

Comment: Nope I didn't assume r greater than 0 as I thought there wasn't any need to do so

Comment: You don’t need to assume $r\geq0$, but you must end up with something that produces $|r|$ in the end.

Comment: Notice that for any real number $a$, $\cos(a) = \cos(-a)$. In particular, it suffices to solve the problem in the case $r \geq 0$.

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: Note: the integrand is positive, so you could you get a negative answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating by part:
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {1-\cos(rx)}{x^2}\, \mathrm dx = \int_{+\infty}^0 (1 - \cos(rx)) \mathrm d \frac 1 x =\left. \frac {1-\cos(rx)}x \right\vert_{+\infty}^0  - r\int_{+\infty}^0 \frac {\sin(rx)}x\, \mathrm dx = r \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\sin(rx)}x \,\mathrm dx. 
$$
Now 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator\sgn{sgn}
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\sin(rx)}x \,\mathrm dx =\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\sin(rx)}{rx}\,\mathrm d(rx)=
\begin{cases}\displaystyle
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\sin u}u\, \mathrm du, & r > 0,\\
0, & r=0,\\ \displaystyle 
\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac {\sin u}u\, \mathrm du, & r < 0,
\end{cases}
= \sgn r \cdot \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\sin u}u\, \mathrm du = \sgn r \cdot \frac \pi 2,
$$
hence the integral equals
$$
r \sgn r \cdot \frac \pi 2 = \frac \pi 2 \vert r \vert. 
$$

The implicit assumption could be $r>0$ when dealing the integral $\int_0^{+\infty} \sin(rx)\,\mathrm dx /x$.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers explain how you get $|r|$ in your answer, but here’s why it *should* happen:

Notice that $1-\cos(rx) \geq 0$ for all $x$, regardless of what $r$ is. Integrating a nonnegative function over any interval should give you a nonnegative value.